# My transaction had a higher gas price but failed. Why?

Tags: web3js, ethers.js, opensea

this is my transaction,
https://etherscan.io/tx/0xd4267bb7e5a22ef8490dd3cfa82b7fefba0bf9ed00d9af891f7988e1027c1637

this is the successful transaction,
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x12ca126f1c833a83dba06b6f2a58ac5d30579b2e7b2da7aa69484a486e78d712

we were buying the same item on opensea,
https://opensea.io/assets/ethereum/0x8dcb8b2d721c022552d826f8bcf2995747248d31/3970

my transaction has a higher gas price, 170 gwei, while his 167 gwei.
Why mine failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transaction failed because although you were in the same block and the max gas you picked was higher, his `Max Priority` was 167.4 gwei while yours was 163 gwei. This means he tipped the miner 3.4 gwei more, and as such, they ordered the block by mining his `first` while mining yours `third`.